# Change Implementation for Spring Namespaces (exchange a bean)

Tags: spring, configuration, namespaces, integration

I have a question about Spring Integration (or basically Spring in common):
I use the a WebService Inbound Gateway in my Spring XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd" >

    <int-ws:inbound-gateway
    id="ws-in-gw-user"
    request-channel="in-user"
    reply-channel="out-user"
    mapped-request-headers="*"
    />
...
</beans>
```

When I use `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>` Tag, a `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway` is created. Now I want to exchange this implemantation with a self written extension of this class. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) bean.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class SimpleWebServiceInboundGatewayBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName){
        if(bean instanceof SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway) {
            return new MyCustomWebSerivceInboundGateway();
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)    {
        return bean;
    }   
}
```

In your config:

```
<bean class="....SimpleWebServiceInboundGatewayBeanPostProcessor" />
```

A `BeanPostProcessor` allows you to exhange beans during initialization.

Comment: Hi reagten, thanks for your reply. This works fine, but will change EVERY XML configuration. In my understanding die XML Tags are a short description for describing some beans. Is there a way to find out what beans I have to define in my configuration instead of the int-ws:inbound-gateway Tag =

Comment: what do you mean by "change EVERY XML configuration?". the BeanPostProcessor is applied to every bean that is created during initialization, and you can test for Type and Bean-Name, thus other beans stay unchanged.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-ws/4.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/integration/ws/config/WebServiceInboundGatewayParser.java#WebServiceInboundGatewayParser

Comment: Okay, I now see the the point and it works, but (there is always a 'but') I now have to set all attributes (like replyChannel) on my own, and the SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway does not offer the getters I need. And I also even do not what the attribute 'mapped-request-headers="*" ' in the XML configuration does (there is no such named attribute in the class hierarchie).

Comment: Otherwise I could also write something like
<bean class="com.provinzial.promakler.tgicgateway.spring.CustomWebServiceInboundGateway"
   id="ws-in-gw-autorisierung">
   <property name="requestChannel" ref="in-autorisierung"/>
   <property name="replyChannel" ref="out-autorisierung"/>
</bean>